# Palindrome program in python using file i/o

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python and working on a few programs to get a hang of it. 
I am making a palindrome program which takes input from a file and prints out the words that are palindromes. Here is the code i have so far

```
def isPalindrome(word):
    if len(word) < 1:
        return True
    else:
        if word[0] == word[-1]:
            return isPalindrome(word[1:-1])
        else:
            return False

def fileInput(filename):
    file = open(filename,'r')
    fileContent = file.readlines()
    if(isPalindrome(fileContent)):
        print(fileContent)
    else:
        print("No palindromes found")
    file.close()
```

this is the file

```
moom
mam
madam
dog
cat
bat
```

i get output of no palindromes found.

Comment: Don't use `file` as a variable name. It shadows the builtin.

Comment: will change it as as soon as i am done writing this. Thanks

Comment: @SukritKalra: from the `print` syntax, the OP might be using Python 3, and `file` isn't a (standard-scope) builtin anymore.

Comment: Your `ispalindrome` is based on checking if a *word* is a palindrome... `file.readlines()` returns a *list* of words... and you're passing that... So your comparisions with be comparing the first and last words in the file etc.... Not the letters of each word...

Comment: @DSM yes i am using python 3.xx

Comment: @DSM : Oops! Missed that. Thanks for the reminder. :)

Comment: @SukritKalra: heh. I always notice it because I was always annoyed that the very natural `for file in files:` clobbered a builtin, and I was happy they fixed it. :^)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The contents of the file will be read in as a list, so fileContent will end up as:

```
fileContent = file.readlines()
fileContent => ["moon\n", "mam\n", "madam\n", "dog\n", "cat\n", "bat\n"]
```

you could fix this by:

```
def fileInput(filename):
    palindromes = False
    for line in open(filename):
        if isPalindrome(line.strip()):
             palindromes = True
             print(line.strip(), " is a palindrome.")

    return "palindromes found in {}".format(filename) if palindromes else "no palindromes found."
```

Note: have added the `palindromes` flag for the purposes of returning the final "palindromes [not] found" statement

Answer (score 0):

There should be a loop on the words in the file. Also `readline` reads the end-of-line character too. You should `strip` it before calling isPalindrome.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
fileContent = file.readline().strip()
```

Because `readlines()` returns list of the string with `'\n'` character.

Also `readlines()` returns a list where as `readline()` returns a current line.

Also dont use `file` as variable name.

So your revised `fileInput()` :

```
def fileInput(filename):
    f = open(filename,'r')
    line = f.readline().strip()
    while line != '':
        if(isPalindrome(line)):
            print(line)
        else:
            print("No palindromes found")
        line = f.readline().strip()
    file.close()
```